# Schema linking via @id results in "Unnamed item" error

Tags: schema, json-ld, google-rich-snippets

I am trying to add Schema structured data to my website.

I have one page for my app with:

```
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org",
  "@type": "MobileApplication",
  "@id": "https://example.com/app",
  "name": "APP",
  "applicationCategory": "HealthApplication",
  "operatingSystem": ["iOS", "Android"],
  "offers": {
    "@type": "Offer",
    "price": "0",
    "priceCurrency": "USD"
  },
  "aggregateRating": {
    "@type": "AggregateRating",
    "ratingValue": "5",
    "ratingCount": "100"
  }
}
```

...and another for my company:

```
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org",
  "@type": "Corporation",
  "@id": "https://example.com/about",
  "name": "COMPANY",
  "owns": {
    "@type": "MobileApplication",
    "@id": "https://example.com/app"
  }
}
```

When I test the above with https://search.google.com/test/rich-results, the app page is fine, but the company page gives the following error:

[image]

Am I misunderstanding how `@id` works? I thought Google would then look for the linked resource and get all the missing properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reference them by using just the `@id` keyword, omit the `@type` keyword:

```
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org",
  "@type": "Corporation",
  "@id": "https://example.com/about",
  "name": "COMPANY",
  "owns": {
    "@id": "https://example.com/app"
  }
}
```

However, Google doesn't seem to utilize `@id` keyword in a way that it links snippets on the internet, especially ones that are on different pages, or sites, or at least there are no benefits in SERP

Also, corporation markup could be improved: property [owns](https://schema.org/owns) expects a [Product](https://schema.org/Product) type, and [MobileApplication](https://schema.org/MobileApplication) is a subtype of [CreativeWork](https://schema.org/CreativeWork), so it's probably not appropriate, however, there seems to be no straightforward property that connects [Organization](https://schema.org/Organization) and [CreativeWork](https://schema.org/CreativeWork), although Google doesn't seem to complain about it

Comment: Yes I tried that as well, but then Google doesn't recognize the item at all, like you said. Should I then put ALL the properties of the linked resource instead of using `@id`? Even though it's a duplicate from another page? (And thanks for the heads up regarding `Product`)

Comment: @TonaldDrump yes, you'd repeat the whole code. however, snippets should be relevant to the page, so not sure how duplicating the app would be interpreted in that case, it depends on the content (not sure if there are multiple snippets per page in the SERP anyway).. so maybe just separate them, each on its page, also, maybe use `LocalBusiness`, instead of `Corporation`

Comment: So here's another place where I used the `@id`; For the `MobileApplication` I would link the `Corporation` as a `Publisher`. But I guess it's not really necessary because Google already knows that the App belongs to that Corporation?

Comment: @TonaldDrump yeah, it's probably tied to the website, although they don't really use/mention that at all. I think `@id` was used only with `LocalBusiness` (although not sure for what..), but it was removed..

Comment: I include enough on the copy to validate and keep the @id to indicate that it still represents the same entity as on the other page.